# Hide editor with specific post meta value

Tags: customization, editor

Is there a way to remove the post editor with specific custom post meta?

Supposed that I have a key edit where a put the string "true" or "false"  and I want to show the editor with true and hide with false, I used this code:

```
function my_remove()
{
  global $post;
  $edit = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_edit', true  );

  if ($edit === 'false') {
    remove_post_type_support( 'post' , 'editor' );
  }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'my_remove');
```

I think the problem is that when admin_init fires there isn't a post yet, but if I use this function when I'm in a post, for instance by using $_POST value, I think I can't disable editor anymore...

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide some more context, such as what problem this is trying to solve, and why?

Comment: I want to use a private meta to enable and disable the content, cause I have page where I only use a template and I don't want that the client can change the content. For this I need a relationship between a custom meta value and the editor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right; `admin_init` is too early to use the global `$post` variable. Fortunately, the post id is passed to the URL when editing a post.

The following code will remove post type support for a post when the `_edit` meta key's value is set to the string false. There are checks in place to ensue this only happens if a post is being edited and it's a `post` post type.

```
/**
 * Removes support for editor when posts have the
 * _edit meta key set to false.
 */
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_remove_editor' );
function wpse_remove_editor() {
    // Use $pagenow to determine what page is being viewed.
    global $pagenow;

    // Get the post ID and the action from the URL.
    $the_id = isset( $_REQUEST['post'] ) && $_REQUEST['post'] ? $_REQUEST['post'] : false;
    $edit_action = isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && 'edit' === $_REQUEST['action'] ? $_REQUEST['action'] : false;

    // Bail if we're not editing a post or we can't get the post ID.
    if ( 'post.php' !== $pagenow || ! $edit_action || ! $the_id ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the post object using the post id.
    $the_post = get_post( $the_id );

    // Bail if we can't get the post object, or if it's not the post post type.
    if ( ! $the_post || 'post' !== $the_post->post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get value for the _edit meta key.
    $use_editor = get_post_meta( $the_id, '_edit', true );

    // Disable editor if value is string "false". Note strict comparison. 
    if ( 'false' === $use_editor ) {
        remove_post_type_support( 'post' , 'editor' );
    }
}
```